# How is a misdeclared weight of a mail bag handled?

Tags: weight-and-balance, cargo

What is the proper process when a postal administration tenders a mail bag with under declared weight?

Is the bag returned to the postal administration or is the bag weight altered to match the actual weight or is there no weight verification of mail bags?

Comment: Are you thinking about mail that is transported in the cargo hold of passenger airplanes? That cargo is usually transported in [ULDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_load_device), which are weighed as a whole before loading.

Comment: Could you clarify what is the aviation-related aspect you're asking about?

Comment: You may precise if your question is more about weight and CG computation or more about cargo handling and facturation or about something else. I think you may begin by a question about weight verification mechanism only to avoid too broad questions.